# R - Hadoop - rmr2 - SVM Model - conver result "list" class to original class "svm.formula" "svm"

Tags: r, class, hadoop, mapreduce, svm

I have following R configuration:

OS:Linux
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
rmr2 version 2.2.1
rhdfs version 1.0.6
hadoop version 1.2.0

How can i convert result of svm model by using hadoop with rmr2 package? So i can use builded model as usual uses like:

```
predict(svm1, "new data")
```

I have folowing code:

```
# set eviremonet variables
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="~/Downloads/hadoop-1.2.0/bin/hadoop")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME="~/Downloads/hadoop-1.2.0/")

# start hadoop

# load librarys
library(rmr2)
library(rhdfs)
library(e1071)

# load sample data
data(iris)

# init hdfs
hdfs.init()

# push data to hdfs
iris.dfs <- to.dfs(iris)

# define map function
iris.map <- function(k, v) 
  {
  svm(v$Species ~ ., data=v)
  }

# rum mar job
iris.svm <- mapreduce(input=iris.dfs, map=iris.map)

# get result back
iris.res <- from.dfs(iris.svm)

svm1 <- svm(iris$Species ~ ., data=iris)

class(iris.res)
class(svm1)
```

The result of both class show folowing:

```
> class(iris.res)
[1] "list"
> class(svm1)
[1] "svm.formula" "svm"

> str(svm1)
List of 30
 $ call           : language svm(formula = iris$Species ~ ., data = iris)
 $ type           : num 0
 $ kernel         : num 2
 $ cost           : num 1
 $ degree         : num 3
 $ gamma          : num 0,25
 $ coef0          : num 0
 $ nu             : num 0,5
 $ epsilon        : num 0,1
 $ sparse         : logi FALSE
 $ scaled         : logi [1:4] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 $ x.scale        :List of 2
  ..$ scaled:center: Named num [1:4] 5,84 3,06 3,76 1,20
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  ..$ scaled:scale : Named num [1:4] 0,828 0,436 1,765 0,762
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
 $ y.scale        : NULL
 $ nclasses       : int 3
 $ levels         : chr [1:3] "setosa" "versicolor" "virginica"
 $ tot.nSV        : int 51
 $ nSV            : int [1:3] 8 22 21
 $ labels         : int [1:3] 1 2 3
 $ SV             : num [1:51, 1:4] -1,743 -1,864 -0,173 -0,535 -1,501 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:51] "9" "14" "16" "21" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
 $ index          : int [1:51] 9 14 16 21 23 24 26 42 51 53 ...
 $ rho            : num [1:3] -0,0203 0,1312 -0,0629
 $ compprob       : logi FALSE
 $ probA          : NULL
 $ probB          : NULL
 $ sigma          : NULL
 $ coefs          : num [1:51, 1:2] 0,0891 0,0000 0,8652 0,0000 0,0000 ...
 $ na.action      : NULL
 $ fitted         : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:150] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ decision.values: num [1:150, 1:3] 1,20 1,06 1,18 1,11 1,19 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:150] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "setosa/versicolor" "setosa/virginica" "versicolor/virginica"
 $ terms          :Classes 'terms', 'formula' length 3 iris$Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width
  .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(iris$Species, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)
  .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:5, 1:4] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "iris$Species" "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" ...
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:4] 1 1 1 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= num 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(iris$Species, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)
  .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:5] "factor" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "iris$Species" "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "svm.formula" "svm"
> str(iris.res)
List of 2
 $ key: NULL
 $ val:List of 30
  ..$ call           : language svm(formula = v$Species ~ ., data = v)
  ..$ type           : num 0
  ..$ kernel         : num 2
  ..$ cost           : num 1
  ..$ degree         : num 3
  ..$ gamma          : num 0,25
  ..$ coef0          : num 0
  ..$ nu             : num 0,5
  ..$ epsilon        : num 0,1
  ..$ sparse         : logi FALSE
  ..$ scaled         : logi [1:4] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
  ..$ x.scale        :List of 2
  .. ..$ scaled:center: Named num [1:4] 5,84 3,06 3,76 1,20
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  .. ..$ scaled:scale : Named num [1:4] 0,828 0,436 1,765 0,762
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  ..$ y.scale        : NULL
  ..$ nclasses       : int 3
  ..$ levels         : chr [1:3] "setosa" "versicolor" "virginica"
  ..$ tot.nSV        : int 51
  ..$ nSV            : int [1:3] 8 22 21
  ..$ labels         : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ SV             : num [1:51, 1:4] -1,743 -1,864 -0,173 -0,535 -1,501 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:51] "9" "14" "16" "21" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  ..$ index          : int [1:51] 9 14 16 21 23 24 26 42 51 53 ...
  ..$ rho            : num [1:3] -0,0203 0,1312 -0,0629
  ..$ compprob       : logi FALSE
  ..$ probA          : NULL
  ..$ probB          : NULL
  ..$ sigma          : NULL
  ..$ coefs          : num [1:51, 1:2] 0,0891 0,0000 0,8652 0,0000 0,0000 ...
  ..$ na.action      : NULL
  ..$ fitted         : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:150] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ decision.values: num [1:150, 1:3] 1,20 1,06 1,18 1,11 1,19 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:150] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "setosa/versicolor" "setosa/virginica" "versicolor/virginica"
  ..$ terms          :Classes 'terms', 'formula' length 3 v$Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(v$Species, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:5, 1:4] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "v$Species" "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:4] 1 1 1 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= num 0
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0xb639820> 
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(v$Species, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:5] "factor" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" ...
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "v$Species" "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" ...
```

But how to convert the result list to the same class as usual smv call?

Comment: What's actually in the list `iris.res`? Call `class` and `str` on each element (or the whole list)?

Comment: @joran please consider my changes on my question.

Comment: But there's nothing to do. Your update clearly shows that (shocker!) Hadoop returned a key-value pair, and the value in this case is precisely the fitted model object.

Comment: @joran Yes, but the class is diffent. And that is my problem. I don't know how to correct this. I have on the one hand a "list" an on the other "svm.formula" with the same values. If i call: predict(iris.res), then i get an error that it can't apply to a "list". And if i convert it manualy with "class(iris.res) <- c("svm.formula", "svm")" and then i call predict again, i get NULL as result. By the regular model i get predictive values.

Comment: I don't know how else to say this. The fitted model object is _the second element of your list_. Why would you run `predict(iris.res)` rather than `predict(iris.res[[2]])`? Once again, Hadoop has returned a key-value pair. You **just want the value**.

Comment: @joran Because i get an error with 'not applicable to list', if i call somthing like this:   predict(iris.res[[2]], iris[1, 1:4])

Comment: `class(iris.res[[2]]) <- class(svm1)` maybe?

Comment: @joran YES, that is. Many Thanks. But Why is applying class by "class(iris.res[[2]]) <- c("svm.formula", "svm")" dindn't work?

Comment: Some experiments and thinking later. It was my mistake. It works fine like this 'iris.res <- values(from.dfs(iris.svm)); class(iris.res) <- c("svm.formula", "svm");sum(predict(iris.res, iris[, -5]) != iris$Species)/length(iris$Species)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap `svm(v$Species ~ ., data=v)` in a `list` call in the map function as in `list(svm(v$Species ~ ., data=v))`. Maps can only return lists, matrices, vectors and data frames. If you returned a model(apparently, not that I implemented it deliberately) it gets coerced to a list. Maybe I could defensively do that whenever the return value is not one of the four supported, just slap a `list` around it, but I don't want to try and be too smart and make too many guesses. The other problem with your approach is that the map function will be called on an arbitrary subset of the data set (for larger data sets), so you will get a list of models in output (well, after you call values on the output). So now you have multiple svms and what do you do, you treat it as an ensamble? But the subsets in the map phase are arbitrary, they don't have any statistical property, like being randomized. It seems to me you think rmr has superpowers to make the svm function parallel distributed, but it doesn't, it will just call it in parallel on a cluster on different chunks of the data. On a small example there is only one chunk, but that's deceptive. Try `rmr.options(keyval.length = 3)` to see what happens with very small chunks (not for production). A different approach would be to build the model on the largest sample you can load on a single machine and then run predict in parallel. That of course is not as scalable in the learning phase but I know of big startups that do just that. Take a look at the resampling article on the cloudera blog by Uri Laserson, I think it will give you some good ideas. Finally we have a dedicated forum for rmr and related packages on Google groups, you are very welcome to join our community.

Comment: It is my first try on Hadoop with R. And in fact i want to go in direction to bagging and ensamble different models like SVMs and RandomForests. And do it parallel distributed. I want read the article and try to reproduce the code from named blog. Thanks for your comment and advice to the blog.